# MS Word Online add-in: How to detect focus?

Tags: javascript, ms-word, event-handling, office-js, office-addins

In developing a Microsoft Word Online add-in, my team needs to detect focus being gained/regained by the document (ETA: to trigger other functionality which depends on this knowledge). It appears that Microsoft has tightly locked down scriptability in this context--all window.on* functions are replaced by null, all error-handling code is deeply obfuscated, etc. Our efforts so far have been frustrated.

Simply setting window.onfocus to a new function causes the add-in to not load correctly, likely because it's triggering a code analyzer as unsafe, but hard to tell.

There is also nothing in the [Microsoft Word Online JavaScript API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/overview/word-add-ins-reference-overview) which directly provides this functionality. Scripts can detect when the document selection has changed easily with a provided method, but that seems to be about it for documented functionality in this area. (Obviously simply sensing document changes will not work.)

What's the best approach to sensing document and/or window focus in this situation? Thank you.

Comment: sounds like an xy problem. what is your end goal?

Comment: I'm not up on the local lingo enough to know what an "xy problem" is. The goal is to sense focus--this is a key part of the system implementation that will not change. If you like, the goal may be described as "send notification to another system that our Word Online Add-In has gotten focus", but it's beside the point.

Comment: https://xyproblem.info

Comment: Thanks. That seems clearly inapplicable here. Sensing focus is a common need in web development and universally in UI development in general--it's just blocked in this context and our integration (which is proprietary intellectual property and cannot be discussed in full here in any event) depends on finding a workaround.

Comment: @DanielA.White None of these seem to have been the subject of gatekeeping as "xy problems". I'm jus' sayin'. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=detect+focus The context here is a Word Online add-in/plugin which needs to sense focus because UI and other features depend on that knowledge.

Comment: This sounds like a feature request; if that's the case, you may want to go to [Microsoft 365 Developer Platform Ideas Forum](https://aka.ms/m365dev-suggestions) and see if your feature has already been requested or request a new feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [**document.onvisibilitychange**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/onvisibilitychange) event can be used as a rough approximation of the required functionality.

```js
document.onvisibilitychange = (ev) => {
  if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
    // Handle pseudo-focus event
  }
  else {
    // Handle pseudo-blur event
  }
};
```

This may be combined as desired with with the Office Online API [**DocumentSelectionChanged**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.eventtype?view=word-js-preview#office_Office_EventType_DocumentSelectionChanged_member) event to refine further to sense when the cursor is placed within the Word document. (That is, fire focus-gained logic only when the Office DocumentSelectionChanged event is fired the first time after the browser document.onvisibilitychange event fired with document.visibilityState equal to "visible".)